# Feed format for woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, import, csv, automation

I am using woocommerece for my website. I get product feed from different suppliers in excel format with different information in different columns (no consistency in product attributes such as price, title, image, stock etc.). Each time I get the feed, I need to adjust (do manual things) the csv to import to woocommerce and I have used [Woocommerce CSV importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-csvimport/) for this purpose. The problem here is I can receive feed from more suppliers and manual work will be time consuming. Is there a way I can submit the feed that suppliers provide and get the csv that can be imported to woocommerce using the plugin I have mentioned above (any plugin or online service that will cost less and less time consuming).

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Many Importing plugins have this functionality where the import are done periodically as set by the admin in settings.
- Some Import Plugins also provides facilities to upload products from a specific URL. In this approach you can just tell a Supplier to add his CSV in a server site where he will always update it whenever he has new products. The Import Plugin will create all the new products and keep the existing products unchanged/updated.
- The best and by far more convenient way is to leverage the existing feature which the plugin WooCommerce gives i.e WooCommerce Rest API. Using this API you can supplier can create/update/delete products on your site directly.

Do research on the given approaches and find the best fit for your needs.